# Structure of Euclidean boundary of Dirichlet region having infinite area

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\Gamma$ be a Fuchsian group. Choosing any point $p\in \Bbb H^2$ not fixed by any non-identity element of $\Gamma$, we can construct a hyperbolically convex connected fundamental region, called Dirichlet region, denoted by $D_p$. Also, $\partial D_p$ is contained in the geodesic $\{z\in \Bbb H^2:d(z,p)=d(z,\gamma p)\}$ for any $\gamma\in \Gamma\backslash \{\text{Id}\}$, i.e., hyperbolic area of $\partial D_p$ is zero.

Note that $D_p$ is closed in $\Bbb H^2$ but may not be in $\widetilde{\Bbb H^2}:=\Bbb H^2\cup \Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$. Let $\widetilde{D_p}$ be the closure w.r.t.  $\widetilde{\Bbb H^2}$. Then,  $\widetilde{D_p}\backslash D_p$ may have uncountably many components. A component having positive $($Euclidean$)$length is called *free side of $D_p$*$($there are at most countably many free sides$)$. Any other component is a point: a point in $\widetilde{D_p}\backslash D_p$ is a *proper vertex* if it is the end-point of two sides$($in $\Bbb H^2)$ of $D_p$, and a point in $\widetilde{D_p}\backslash D_p$ is a *improper vertex* if it is the end-point of a side$($in $\Bbb H^2)$ and a free-side of $D_p$.

> $\textbf{Question 1:}$ Is it possible that there is a point in
> $\widetilde{D_p}\backslash D_p$ that is neither proper nor improper
> vertex?

> $\textbf{Question 2:}$ Are the number of free sides, proper or
> improper vertices independent of the chosen point $p$? In other words,
> is it possible to find some invariants for $\Gamma$ for counting free
> sides, proper or improper vertices $($after classifying under some
> equivalence relations$)$?

The above two questions are motivated by the following statements  for any $p$ not fixed by any non-identity element of $\Gamma$:

$(1)$ $D_p$ has no free side  $\iff$ $(2)$ $D_p$ has a finite hyperbolic area  $\implies$ $(3)$ $D_p$ has finitely many sides$($in $\Bbb H^2)$ $\impliedby$ $(4)$ $\Gamma$ is finitely generated $\iff$ $(5)$ $\Bbb H^2/\Gamma$ is topologically finite.

Here, $\Bbb H^2/\Gamma$ topologically finite means $\Bbb H^2/\Gamma$ is an orbifold with *finite genus*, *finite number of marked points*$($the number of these points corresponds to the number of conjugacy classes of maximal elliptic cyclic subgroups$)$, *a finite number of punctures*$($the number of these punctures corresponds to the number of conjugacy classes of maximal parabolic subgroups$)$.

Comment: What is your definition of a Fuchsian group?

Comment: Discrete subgroup of $\text{PSL}(2,\Bbb R)=\text{Iso}^+(\Bbb H^2)$. But I am not getting any idea from this hint. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: It was not a hint but a request for a clariufication. With your definition, the equivalence statements you are quoting are simply false. You need to assume finite generation. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716033/fuchsian-groups-of-the-first-kind-and-lattices/3376910#3376910

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out my fault. Actually, $(2)\implies (3)$ by Siegel's Theorem, but $(3)\implies (2)$ if we assume $\Gamma$ is of the first kind, otherwise, the Dirichlet region may have a free side. $(1)\iff(2)$, $(4)\iff(5)$ and $(4)\implies (3)$ in any case. But, $(3)$ does **not** imply $(4)$ in general, and this can be interpreted(though I have no concrete counterexample) as there is an infinite-type surface having a geometrically finite Dirichlet region. Can you tell me something about $(2)\implies (4),(4)\implies(2)$ in the general case or some counterexample?

Comment: Also, while writing my question, I used [this .pdf](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-0-8176-4653-0_2.pdf) which is the second chapter of [this book](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-33877-4_3). Theorem 2.10. here is certainly not hold in general, as you already said. Similarly, [here theorem 2.4](http://www.fuchs-braun.com/media/7c48db97e18c2326ffff802affffffef.pdf). The authors of these two are the same.  Thanks again.

Comment: Searching further, I got this: If a Fuchsian group has a fundamental region of a finite hyperbolic area then is of the first kind. So,  by your answer, in this case, the Fuchsian group is finitely generated, i.e. we have $(2)\implies (4)$. So, I need a finite type surface with an infinite hyperbolic area(may be $\Bbb H^2$) and an infinite-type surface having a geometrically finite Dirichlet region.

Comment: I will add an answer later today.

Comment: Sure, thanks, I will wait for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct implications are:

(0) The limit set $\Lambda$ of $\Gamma$ is the entire circle $S^1$ (i.e. $\Gamma$ is of the first kind) $\iff$ (1) $D_p$ has no free side  $\Leftarrow$ (2) $D_p$ has a finite hyperbolic area  $\implies$ (3) $D_p$ has finitely many sides  $\iff$ (4) $\Gamma$ is finitely generated $\iff$ (5) the orbifold $\Bbb H^2/\Gamma$ is topologically finite.

The equivalence (0)$\iff$(1) comes from the fact that $D_p$ is a fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ in ${\mathbb H}^2$ and, moreover, the complement $\overline{D_p} \setminus \Lambda$ is a fundamental domain for the action of $\Gamma$ on $\overline{{\mathbb H}^2}\setminus \Lambda$.

There are many examples where $\Gamma$ is of the first kind but $D_p$ has infinite area (equivalently, $\Bbb H^2/\Gamma$ has **infinite**  area), one is given in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716033/fuchsian-groups-of-the-first-kind-and-lattices/3376910#3376910). The implication (2)$\Rightarrow$(1) is clear. The implications

(2)$\Rightarrow$(3)$\iff$(4)$\iff$(5)

are tricky and you can find proofs in

A.F.Beardon, "Geometry of Discrete Groups", Springer Verlag, 1983.

Comment: Is not it "equivalently $\Bbb H^2/\Gamma$ has **in**finite area"? in the first line of the third paragraph. Also, $(0)$ I can think of as an isolated one (as it is specific to the first kind), and the rest of (bi)implications do hold for any case(means irrespective of kind of $\Gamma$). Am I right?

Comment: @User: Right, corrected. (0) is included because it is a standard condition equivalent to (1) in your list.